# Conversion Failed when converting varchar value to data type smallint

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to use an Update SQL query to set a series of values in a table, however I am facing an issue whereby I keep getting the error message

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
> '&[NAS_APIConfig.ProcessID_FS]&' to data type smallint.

Here is an example of a query I am using:

```
UPDATE tblNAS_APIConfig
SET ProcessID_FS = '&[NAS_APIConfig.ProcessID_FS]&',
    ScheduleType = '&[NAS_APIConfig.ScheduleType]&'
```

The data is being stored in a collection within Blue Prism and was pulled from a different database with a data type of smallint. I'm guessing that when the data is being pulled into Blue Prism it is getting cast as a varchar data type. What is the correct syntax to use the UPDATE SET query while casting the item as smallint?

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Which API/interface?

Comment: No WHERE clause needed? Do you really want to update all rows?

Comment: How are you expecting a string value of '&[NAS_APIConfig.ProcessID_FS]&' to be written to smallint column?